# How do I search by a table included using with() statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to search with a column on a connected table using with. [According to laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) the following should work.

```
$lineItems = Invoice::with(['invoiceHeader' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('community_id', '=', 1);
    }, 'invoiceLineItems'])
        ->limit(10)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

However, I don't get anything from the `invoiceHeader` table and I get all the invoices available. If I take out the function I get the same but with `invoiceHeader`'s table values showing up.

```
$lineItems = Invoice::with(['invoiceHeader', 'invoiceLineItems'])
        ->limit(10)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

It seems I might be doing something of a `right join` where I get all the Invoices but then only the invoiceHeader values when applicable to the foreign key.

Edit:

I put `->toSql();` after the `limit()` and it shows I only get the following.

```
"select * from `invoice` limit 10"
```

Comment: can you post relation and db schema .also do you have records in invoice header table where community_id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) mixing with `with`:

```
$lineItems = Invoice::with(['invoiceHeader', 'invoiceLineItems'])
    ->whereHas('invoiceHeader', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('community_id', 1);
    })
    ->limit(10)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```